# Python : How to create a dynamic list of class values

Tags: python, list, class, dynamic

I have tried to find the anwser to that question, but I cannot find the good Keywords ...

I want to know how can I create a list of value help in instances of a class. 
What I do not want is that :

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,i)
        self.i = i

inst1 = Test(2)
inst2 = Test(5)

MyList = [inst1.i,inst2.i]
```

At that point MyList = [2,5]
if I change the value if inst1

```
inst1.i = 4
print MyList 
[2,5]
```

MyList is STILL [2,5] but I want it to be updated to [4,5]

```
print MyList
[4,5]
```

So my question is that, how do I create a list that points to the variable and not the variable value ?

If you want to know why : I am running a MonteCarlo simulation in which I have a lot of proteins, each with one energy value, and each Protein is instantiated from a Protein class.

```
class Protein:
    def __init__(self,sequence,energy):
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.energy = energy
```

That energy value of some proteins gets updated during a montecarlo simulation. I need a list of all the energies to perform some calculation on the distribution. Right know, I updated the list with a for loop, but it would be way more efficient if I could have a list that points to the variable, that way every time an energy in the Protein class is changed the list is updated automatically.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why not store the instances directly in the list, and manipulate those? `MyList = [inst1, inst2]`, then you have a list of references to your instances. Any changes to the instances are visible in the list too.

Comment: Can you explain why you need the int value and not the class instance in the list? Some kind of cute proxy object could probably be created but @MartijnPieters suggestion is probably the easy way forward. There is not a simple way to store a ref to an int.

Comment: Yes, I though about that, but how can I get the value then ? 
for example if I want to get the histogram and I do : 

    hist,bin = np.histogram(MyList) 

it won't work.

Comment: What if I create the class inheriting the int class ? would that work ?

Comment: `hist,bin = np.histogram([x.i for x in MyList])` should work. And you can always write your class so that it behaves like an int when you need it to, the beauty of python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good question.

Two bullet-points on the way to your answer:

1. classical variable vs. python label-like "variables"/identifiers
2. mutable vs immutable python-types

You have to keep in mind, that in python the name *variable* may be misleading if you come from another programing language. It may be better not to talk about *variables*, but about "*labels*".

When you create an object like: `myvar = 1` you create (oversimplification) an object `1` and to keep track of it you attached a label `myvar` to it.
So if you want to talk about the object `1` you could say: "The object labeled with `myvar`." You may reattach the label to another object by relabeling: `myvar = 2`. If `myvar` was the only label on `1` you just lost the object `1` and it will be garbage collected.

In your case:

```
inst1 = Test(2)  # create 2 and attach it to inst1.i
inst2 = Test(5)  # create 5 and attach it to inst2.i
MyList = [inst1.i,inst2.i]  # list of objects: [2 ,5]
```

So you now have a list of 2 immutable objects!
Your next step:

```
inst1.i = 4
```

creates a new object `4` and reattaches the `inst1.i` *label* onto it! You just lost your handle on object `2`. But because it's in the `MyList` collection it's still referenced and won't be garbage collected.

Now on to bullet point 2:

A nice [overview of mutable and immutable](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects) objects, shows that basically all primitive types are immutable and most collections are mutable. The difference is. that mutable objects can get an *in-place* edit, while immutable objects need to be replaced.

Or to keep the *label* anology: On immutable objects you need to move the "Label" while on mutable you hold the "Label" in place and move the object under it.

Now back to your problem:

Basically you need to change perspective! `MyList` is NOT an Array, but a collection. So in order not to reinvent your venue of solution i would recommend to keep the `Test` objects in your list, rather than their values!:

```
MyList = [inst1,inst2]
```

If you change now `inst1.i = 4`, the following happens:

1. you create the object `4`
2. you attach the attribute inst1.i to it ("*re-label*" it)
3. Your object becomes a mediator between the list and your new object
4. You can access `4` over `MyList[0].i` or `inst1.i`

Mission accomplished! ;-)

```
for value in MyList:
    print value.i

inst1.i = 4    
raw_values = [o.i for o in MyList]
[4, 5]

inst1.i = 2
raw_values = [o.i for o in MyList]
[2, 5]
```

Comment: Ok, so int are immutable, while list are mutable.
So that means that as long as I store an int I'm screwed ... anyway to make the int Mutable ?

Comment: Basically yes, but there are ways around it! It's only confussing at the beginning later on it's more good then bad!

Comment: I'm sure it is ! ^^ 
I have been using python for a while, and I usually don't need that ! 
But in that particular algoritm it would avoid a double for loop that would reallly speed up the algorithm.

I think I while inherit the int class to my protein class to make it an int, and then store it in the list, that way it should work.

Comment: Ok I tried that, it doesn't work ^^ It basicaly create an imutable class ! ^^

Comment: Alright, I guess I will have to do with the for loop ^^
I wanted to avoid it because I have to redo that at every step and I have 700K proteins ;) which is slowing down the algorithm ;) 

Thanks !

Comment: ;-) Change perspective! Why do you need to loop? If you only have a hammer, you tend to see every problem as a nail. ;-) So if you are used to C, every algorithm in any language becomes an indexed loop! ;-)

Comment: Completely avoiding to use the word _variable_ which is ambiguous in Python, is a highly sanitary practice, I'm totally with you on this point. However, there's a generic name employed in the doc in place of this horrid word _variable_ and in place of your ``tag`` denomination, it is ``identifier``. In Python there are only identifiers (synonyms: names, references) and objects.

Comment: @eyquem: I concur. But i did adapt the terminology of the OP, because frankly (imho) identifier is almost as misleading as variable. The term "variable" stresses it's own mutability, where identifier it's ability to identify something. Maybe better, but not very much. Tag on the other hand, stresses more the dependency of the object it's attached to, without loosing the semantic concept of being reattached. But that's just my pov. Maybe im biased! ;-)

Comment: Your point of vue is defendable. It's even evoked in (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tag) In fact all nouns ``identifier``, ``name``, ``reference``, ``tag``, ``label`` are synonyms. But the docs employs the first one : (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) It seems to me that the 3 last ones insists ont the mobility of the identifier from one object to another. However ``tag`` brings ambiguity since it's heavily used in the XML text formats.

Comment: No arguments from me. ... i wonder why not use "label" next time, to elaborate the difference between 'variable' in a classical sense and python "identifiers" ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already created various instances of Protein class (ex. p1, p2, p3), and that energy value is a number:

```
class Protein:
    def __init__(self,sequence,energy):
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.energy = energy

def update_list_energy(list, value):
    for prot in list:
        prot.energy += value  #or whatever the update should be

p1 = Protein('AAA', 1)
p2 = Protein('BBB', 2)
p3 = Protein('CCC', 3)

list_of_proteins = [p1,p2,p3]  
print [p.energy for p in list_of_proteins] # prints [1,2,3]
update_list_energy(list_of_proteins, 1)
print [p.energy for p in list_of_proteins] # prints [2,3,4]
```

seems to me the best way to achieve that :)

Comment: Thanks
Yes, that is how I do it, but I want to avoid the for loop so that the algorithm achieve greater speed !

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class ProteinEnergy(int): pass
... 
>>> e = ProteinEnergy(1)
>>> e
1
>>> e + 1
2
>>> class Protein(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.energy = ProteinEnergy(value)
... 
>>> p1 = Protein(1)
>>> p2 = Protein(2)
>>> protein_energies = [p1.energy, p2.energy]
>>> protein_energies
[1, 2]
>>> p1.energy += 5
>>> protein_energies
[1, 2]
>>> class Energy(object):
...     def __init__(self, v):
...         self.v = v
... 
>>> class Protein(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.energy = Energy(value)
... 
>>> p1 = Protein(1)
>>> p2 = Protein(2)
>>> p1.energy.v
1
>>> protein_energies = [p1.energy, p2.energy, ]
>>> p1.energy.v = 5
>>> protein_energies[0].v
>>> 5
```

So no, a simple subclass of int does not cut it. But a new class for Energy will. See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html@emulating-numeric-types for all of the methods you will want to add to Energy to make it look like a number.

Is the effort worth it? You decide.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the `list` class and override the sequence methods. Here's an example:

```
class Protein(list):
    def __init__(self, energy=0):
        self.energy = energy

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.energy -= value - self[key]
        super(Protein, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.energy += value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.energy -= self[key]
        super(Protein, self).__delitem__(key)

    def append(self, value):
        super(Protein, self).append(value)
        self.energy += value
```

Usage:

```
>>> p = Protein()
>>> p.append(1)
>>> print p
[1]
>>> print p.energy
1
>>> 
>>> p.append(5)
>>> print p
[1, 5]
>>> print p.energy
6
>>> 
>>> p[0] = 2
>>> print p
[2, 5]
>>> print p.energy
7
>>> 
>>> del p[1]
>>> print p
[2]
>>> print p.energy
2
```

Depending on how much you are doing with it, you might want to overrwide methods like `extend` and `__add__`

Comment: Your class shouldn't be called ``Protein`` but ``list of energies of proteins``

Comment: @eyquem as he starts adding some more properties to the `Protein` class, such as `name`, it will start to resemble a `Protein`.

Comment: There should be ``self.energy += value - self[key]`` BEFORE ``super(Protein, self).__setitem__(key, value)`` instead of ``self.energy += value`` after

Comment: Don't understand your comment. Do you think that ``p.energy`` being 8 does make sense when ``p`` is ``[2, 5]`` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Protein:
    Energies = []
    def __init__(self,en):
        self.__dict__['energy'] = en
        # this instruction to avoid writing self.i that
        # would call __setattr__(self,'i',x) while
        # attribute L wouldn't be defined at this moment
        self.L = len(self.Energies)
        Protein.Energies.append(en)
        # appended only at the creation of the instance
    def __setattr__(self,name,x):
        self.__dict__[name] = x
        # this writing to avoid recursive call
        if name=='energy':
            Protein.Energies[self.L] = x

inst1 = Protein(2)
inst2 = Protein(5)

print Protein.Energies
print inst1.Energies
print inst2.Energies
print

inst1.energy = 10
print Protein.Energies
print inst1.Energies
print inst2.Energies
```

result

```
[2, 5]
[2, 5]
[2, 5]

[10, 5]
[10, 5]
[10, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you. - I am interested to know if you observe a greater speed in the execution of the program. - I draw your attention to this fact: ``The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods`` (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) It's the reason why we are obliged to write ``Protein.Energies`` inside the methods , not merely ``Energies``, to get access to the list **Energies** which is a class attribute defined in the class block(I write ``Energies`` for the name, and **Energies** for the object).

Comment: When a method encounters the attribute reference ``Protein.Energies``, the function on which the method is based goes out of its namespace because there is no local identifier ``Protein`` in it, and explores the namespace of this outer space, presently the module namespace, in which there is the identifier ``Protein``. Then it searches for the attribute of name ``Energies`` of the class **Protein**. If it was written ``Energies`` instead of ``Protein.Energies`` it wouldn't find the identifier ``Energies`` there, in the module namespace

Comment: By the way, if you prefer it, you can define the list ``Energies`` in the module level, and call it with merely ``Energies`` in the class' methods. But it may collide with the presence of another list already named ``Energies`` in the module, it is more logical to do as I did in my code.